# Praat: Sound analysis

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation, ipa, phonemes, vowels

In Praat after converting stereo sound to mono, the intensity reduced to (-ve) so no sound is produced although the original stereo sound has a max intensity 70 dB !

Comment: Sounds like your two channels are out of phase and cancelling. Try extracting just one channel and working with that.

Comment: There is something about XLR connectors that can cause that, but I forgot what.

Comment: I can go for extracting one channel cause I have no idea about XLR connection..but thanks for your help